# Pandas groupby with value_counts and generating columns in new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe with the 'name' of a particular event, the year it occurred, and its type, which looks like:

```
index  name  year  type  extracolumns
  0    'a'   2014  'X'     stuff
  1    'a'   2014  'X'     stuff
  2    'a'   2014  'Y'     stuff
  3    'a'   2014  'Y'     stuff
  4    'a'   2015  'X'     stuff
  5    'a'   2015  'X'     stuff
  6    'a'   2015  'Y'     stuff
  7    'b'   2014  'X'     stuff
  8    'b'   2015  'Y'     stuff
  9    'c'   2014  'Z'     stuff
```

I would like a dataframe indexed by the event's 'name', that has the count of each 'type', by year. Ideally it will look like:

```
index  type_X_2014  type_Y_2014  type_Z_2014  type_X_2015  type_Y_2015  type_Z_2015
 'a'        2            2            0             2           1           0
 'b'        1            0            0             0           1           0
 'c'        0            0            1             0           0           0
```

This should have nunique(types)*nunique(years) columns. Obviously this will involve groupby and some value_counts. Is there a way to dynamically accomplish this, without hardcoding the column names? Thanks much.

Comment: Would this work? `df.pivot_table(index=["name"],columns=["year","type"],values=["type"],aggfunc="count")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) to create a frequency table:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.width = sys.maxsize
df = pd.DataFrame({'extracolumns': ['stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff'], 'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'name': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], 'type': ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], 'year': [2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014]}) 

result = pd.crosstab(df['name'], [df['year'], df['type']], dropna=False)
result.columns = ['type_{}_{}'.format(typ,year) for year,typ in result.columns]

print(result)
```

yields

```
      type_X_2014  type_Y_2014  type_Z_2014  type_X_2015  type_Y_2015  type_Z_2015
name                                                                              
a               2            2            0            2            1            0
b               1            0            0            0            1            0
c               0            0            1            0            0            0
```

---

If you don't want to hardcode the column names, but you know the position (ordinal index) of the columns then you could use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to reference the columns by position:

```
result = pd.crosstab(df.iloc[:,1], [df.iloc[:, 2], df.iloc[:, 3]])
```

---

The `dropna=False` causes `crosstab` to keep columns even if all the frequencies are all zero. This ensures that there are `nunique(types)*nunique(years)` columns -- including `type_Z_2015`.

Answer (score 0):

First, prepare a summary dataframe:

```
u = df.groupby(['name','year','type']).count()\
                                      .unstack(0).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Unfortunately, it does not have the right index. Now, fix the index by concatenating the first- and second-level indexes:

```
u.index = ['type_{}_{}'.format(*kind[0]) for kind in zip(u.index)]
```

Unfortunately, it does not have the right columns. Now, fix the columns by removing the first-level indexes:

```
u.columns = u.columns.get_level_values(1)
u
#name         a  b  c
#type_X_2014  2  1  0
#type_Y_2014  2  0  0
#type_Z_2014  0  0  1
#type_X_2015  2  0  0
#type_Y_2015  1  1  0
```

And transpose the rows and columns, if you wish:

```
u = u.T
```